# How am I supposed to make the loop/task begin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So, I'm trying to code a Discord Bot with Python 3.9.0 and Discord.py. I've begin to write some codes, and simple commands such as sending messages in the channel the bot is summoned.

Now, I would like to run a loop that occurs (here for the example) every 10 seconds, but I can't initialize it. How am I supposed to do that ?

I already tried typing : vote_auto.start() but it says that it is missing 1 required positionnal argument : "ctx".

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from itertools import cycle

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
     print("Gol.D.Roger Bot est prêt.")
     await vote_auto(ctx).start()

@bot.command()
async def votez(ctx):
     await ctx.send("N’oubliez pas d’aller VOTER ! C'est un nouveau mois qui 
     s'annonce et qui dit nouveau cycle dit RESET TOP-SITE ! Faites de votre 
     mieux pour nous donner la force. C'est aussi pour vous quon veut rester 
     au TOP ! :star_struck:  ET SURTOUT ! Cette semaine compte TRIPLE !!! 
     :fire: :cent: :clap:")
await ctx.send('https://onepieceanarchy.forumactif.com/t479-10-votes-et-recompenses')
await ctx.send('https://media1.tenor.com/images/4f02345231c710ae0a96098086a46c4f/tenor.gif?itemid=14816222')

 @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
  async def vote_auto(ctx):
      print('Loop Vote Begun')
      await ctx.send("N’oubliez pas d’aller VOTER ! C'est un nouveau mois qui s'annonce et qui dit nouveau cycle dit RESET TOP-SITE ! Faites de votre mieux pour nous donner la force. C'est aussi pour vous quon veut rester au TOP ! :star_struck:  ET SURTOUT ! Cette semaine compte TRIPLE !!! :fire: :cent: :clap:")
      await ctx.send('https://onepieceanarchy.forumactif.com/t479-10-votes-et-recompenses')
      await ctx.send('https://media1.tenor.com/images/4f02345231c710ae0a96098086a46c4f/tenor.gif?itemid=14816222')

     bot.run('NzYzMTIwNzI2MjI3MTU3MDEz.X3zFjw.butp19UlqX2h1Om9B6tG3Hr7riQ')
```

[image: Here you can review my code !]

If someone could helped me, please.

Comment: Paste your code here. nobody will type your code from the photo. vote_auto requires a parameter and you are not sending any might be the cause

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm quite new to stack overflow, so I just did a screen capture for the code !
How would I be supposed to add this parameter ? I have tried some things but it doesn't work.

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Gol.D.Roger Bot est prêt.")
    await vote_auto.start()

Comment: You have included your bot token in your question. Anyone can now hijack your bot. You need to regenerate the token on the discord developer website and not use the updated one here. Your task won't work because `ctx` can't be passed. You need to decide which channel/user you want to send the message to and use something like `await channel.send` instead of `await ctx.send`

Comment: Ah yes I forgot that ! I just changed it, thanks for making me notice !

Answer (score 1):

[Docs for discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/)

A `task` does not have a `ctx` parameter, a `ctx` is a [command invocation Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context). Think about it, where is this ctx parameter coming from in a task?

`async def vote_auto(ctx):` should just be `async def vote_auto():`

`task.start()` is not a coroutine, you would just use `vote_auto.start()` To start your task.  As mentioned in the comments you should use [get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Client.get_channel) and then `channel.send` instead of `ctx.send` in your task.